# What is the meaning of the red feather in The Exorcist TV Series?

Tags: the-exorcist, the-exorcist-tv

This question contains spoilers from the Fox TV series *The Exorcist*, not the original film.

In episode 5, Henry Rance

> finds a red feather along with some dried flowers inside a Bible. Henry demands his wife Angela to confess. Angela would later confess to Father Tomas that she is actually Regan MacNeil, the girl from the original *Exorcist* film.

We see the red feather again in episode 9,

> where Father Tomas' secretary hands Father Tomas the book *The Devil Inside My Daughter*, in which he reads a key section that Regan's mother feared that the demon would return to Angela/Regan.

One theory is that a Catholic Cardinal would play an important role since a red feather is the feather for a Catholic Cardinal. Another idea is that the red feather was a sign of divine intervention where God used the red feather to guide others to find out more about Angela Rance.

What would be the meaning of the red feather in *The Exorcist* TV Series?

Comment: Any help here; http://screenertv.com/television/the-exorcist-geena-davis-angela-rance-regan-macneil/?